# How get the content of SQS Message using Lambda in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

everyone.

I'm interested in get the content of SQS Message using Lambda. Let me explain my infrastructure: I have an EC2 instance that has a script like that bellow. So, it script will send to SQS the message containing instance ID.

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://*.*.*.*/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
REGION=$(curl http://*.*.*.*/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed '$s/.$//')
QUEUE-URL=$(...)

aws sqs send-message --queue-url "${QUEUE-URL}" --message-body "${INSTANCE_ID}" --region "${REGION}"
```

The ideia is: when the SQS recieve the message, I would like to trigger a Lambda Function to modificate this instance. But, for that, I need the instance ID. I have searching a lot and unfortunately, I couldn't understand very well how I could get the instance ID, using AWS Lambda, from the SQS Message mentioned above.

I've been trying to solve this problem, but as I don't understand Lambda so much, I searched for many solutions and tested then. Unfortunately, I had no success. So, I interested to learn more about this service.

If someone's could help me with that, I'd be very greateful.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html play around with it for a few days before asking for help.

Comment: Posted a solution yesterday, still unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Lambda function can be configured with the Amazon SQS queue as a 'trigger'.

When a message is sent to the SQS queue, the Lambda function will be invoked. The message both will be available in the Lambda function `body`.

The code would look something like:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
      body = record['body']
      print("From SQS: " + body)
```

It is possible that multiple messages are passed to the Lambda function, so it first loops through each Record, then extracts the passed-in information in the `body` parameter.

The `print()` will show the contents of the message `body` in CloudWatch Logs. Check to make sure it contains what you expect. Then, add code that uses that value.

There is no need for your Lambda function to specifically call SQS -- this is handled automatically by the AWS Lambda service, which will then delete the message from the queue after your Lambda function successfully completes.

Comment: Hi, John.

I'm very grateful for your help. It works for that application. 

I'm new with AWS Lambda and it's great when someone takes a little time to explain the content.

Now, i'm going to keep studying, testing and creating some application scenarios. Thanks a lot, was a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

@John's answer Is all new you need.

Since you are new to AWS. I would tell you answer in a way that will help you to debug for future too.

- You need to first make sure sns topic target is configured as trigger.
- In your lambda function, there is parameter irrespective of any language `event`. This parameter contains the information about the event which triggered the lambda
- Inside the event parameter there is not all the information, like source, event information, in this information you will get Your instance id.
- Just try logging event -> then records and you will get your instance id.
- Then you can play with your Instance ID

Tip : In the console there is lambda test event where you can generate a sample event form different aws services, sns is also there. You can visualise the sample event too before testing with real event form sns .

Docs for reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html#gettingstarted-concepts-event

Comment: Hi, Jatin.

Thanks for your help. My problem was solved and, now, I can keep studying and understanding more and more around this service. Thanks, also, for yours tips, it will be very useful for my learning.